# .bat file to automatically add column to pipeline csv and populate with today's date

Tags: csv, batch-file

I'm very new to .bat files and have excitedly created some to copy, move and rename documents.

Despite searching, I'm getting stuck with a more complex command, largely because the document I'm trying to modify is pipeline delimited rather than 'normal' csv...

My question: Can I, and if I can - how do I take an existing pipeline delimited csv that always has the same number of columns and add a column onto the end with todays date (DD/MM/YYYY) in it for every row?

```
$ awk -F, 'NF>1{$0 = "\"YYYY-MM-DD\"" FS $0}1' file

sed 'N;s/","/","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","/5' file
```

I cant seem to get anything to even modify the document at the moment :-(

Comment: Im thinking I need something like this:

@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "file.csv"') do (
>>"fileout.csv" echo.%%a|%time%
)

Comment: can I delete your question on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8314)

Comment: I haven't got a solution working yet - Currently the date being added is skipping rows. 16000+ rows and 334 are empty in the new column.

Comment: You have not added any of that extra information to your question on DosTips.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch attempt isn't that bad:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "file.csv"') do (
  >>"fileout.csv" echo.%%a|%time%
)
```

Just a few adjustments:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.csv) do (
  echo(%%a^|%time%
))>"fileout.csv"
```

- `for /f` is able to process the contents of a file directly (no need for `type`, although it works fine)
- Redirecting (`>>`) inside the loop is slow, because the file will be opened, and closed every time you write to it (although it works). It's much faster to only once open/close the file (especially with large files).
- `echo.` is not secure (although it works fine in most circumstances), best option is `echo(`.
- The pipe, `|` is a special character and in this case needs escaping with the caret, ^.

Note: `for /f` skips empty lines, so they will not be in the new file. Same with lines, that start with `;` (default EOL)

**Edit** for "adding `|Date` to the Header":

```
@echo off
<file.csv set /p header=
>fileout.csv echo %header%^|DATE
(for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (file.csv) do (
  echo(%%a^|%date%
))>>"fileout.csv"
```

`<file.csv set /p header=` is a way to read just one (the first) line of a file to a variable. Write it back with the new data appended (or leave it unchanged - your comment isn't quite clear about that). Use `skip=1` to skip the first line with further processing.
Don't forget to change `))>"fileout.csv"` to `))>>"fileout.csv"`.

Comment: Hi Stephan. Thanks for your reply. Am I supposed to be seeing a new file in the same folder called fileout.csv?

Comment: Ignore above. I've got it creating the fileout.csv in the same directory, but the contents are blank. Any ideas?

Comment: There are 228 columns in my pipe delimited csv just in case this is where it may be struggling?

Comment: The pipe, **`|`** is a special character and in this case needs escaping with the caret, **`^`**. It should read, `Echo %%a^|%TIME%`.

Comment: @Compo how could I forget... (changed)

Comment: Amazing, thank you gentlemen, I've got it working as you expected. I've changed %time% to %date% for the format I need, but I've discovered my next problem - I need the header for the new column to remain the same, perhaps labelled "DATE". Is this achievable? The program I am using to import the data will not like headers changing at all.

Comment: Hi again, running the code on my prod data this morning - from 16,000 rows, I have 334 that dont have a date added. The 'cell' is blank. I have ran it twice now and the same rows have missing dates at the end. Any ideas why this will be and can the code be tweaked to remedy this in any way?

Comment: My first thought: "this can't happen". Second thought: "... with a proper formatted textfile". Try going back from `... in (file.csv) do ...` to `... in ('type file.csv') do ...`, which should convert all line endings to proper Windows line endings.

Comment: @Stephan, I did some testing with 3 files.  I changed the line endings on each one.  One file with LF, one with CRLF and one with CR.  The CR only file is the problematic one.  Using Type and even piping findstr would not fix the append problem.

Comment: I'm currently toying going back to my MS Excel macro but having discovered batch commands my macro solution seems so amateur and clunky. I really want this to work!

Comment: Glad to hear, there's something more amateur and clunky than batch... `:D`. Analyze your csv file (maybe with a hex editor) to find out, how the failing 334 lines differ from the others.

Comment: I just read `There are 228 columns` - there is a size limit for variables (~8200 for "normal" variables, I'm not sure about `for` variables like `%%a` but I would be surprised if they behave different). Check the line length of the failed lines.

Comment: Hex is beyond my ability but i've done {=SUM(LEN(A1:HT1))} in excel and there is nothing unusual about the rows that dont have a date on the end. The character counts for the rows are all in the same ball-park above and below. The headers are 2951 characters. All rows are around 300 characters. In excel there doesn't appear to be anything at all different about the rows that I can see. Is there a Hex editor/viewer as part of Windows I can try?

Comment: @Stephan, just modifying the code to include the DATE header and I get an error that starts 'RECORD_ID' is not recognised as an internal or external command... RECORD_ID is my 2nd column header. I may have to put this to bed though if there is no way of getting every line to have the date in it.